# How do I restart network manager at logon automatically?

Tags: networking, network-manager

After fiddling around for a long time with a recently purchased USB WiFi adapter (a TP-LINK AC 600 Archer T2UH), I have finally got it working under Ubuntu (KDE neon User Edition 5.6), but only by manually restarting network-manager manually after each login using the following commands:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
```

Note that if I don't issue the above commands after login, the network manager will still start up normally, but no WiFi networks are detected and I cannot establish a WiFi connection. However, by issuing the above commands I am able to select and connect to an access point normally.

I have tried adding the two lines above to ~/.profile so that I don't have to manually type them in each time I log in, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else that would be worth trying? All I really want at this point is to have the above two lines executed automatically after logging in.

Sorry if the solution is obvious. This is my third day using Linux and I think I've hit my troubleshooting limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: If you're using 16.04, you could just use a single command: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`.

Comment: Even `service network-manager restart` should work.